# Reg not incrementing in synchronous always block

Tags: verilog

I am trying to increment a reg `i_Count` when `i_Valid` is signaled

```
always @(posedge i_clk)
begin
  if(i_Valid)
    i_Count <= i_Count+1; //Increments to 1 then stops
end
```

However, my `i_Count` only counts to 1 then for all `i_Valid` signals afterwards, it stays at 1.

I checked the `i_Valid` waveform and it works fine, I also tried to place the increment statement *outside* of the if-block and it works fine too.

```
always @(posedge i_clk)
begin
    i_Count <= i_Count+1; //Works fine
end
```

What went wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

In the first code, `i_Count` increments only when your clock has a positive edge and `i_Valid` is 1 when your clock transitions from 0 to 1(positive edge of `i_clk`).Probably , your `i_Valid` isn't true(1) when the clock transitions.

In the second code,it is incrementing every clock signal as `i_Valid` is not blocking `i_Count`

Comment: I will edit the answer, when you provide more details